# NestJs Websocket, how to test and debug "Socket hang up"?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I have a fairly simple Websocket Server, all I am trying to achieve is to have a socket gateway that would emit events to listening/connected clients based on db status updates.

here is my implementation:

```js
@WebSocketGateway(5010, { transports: ['websocket'], cors: true })
export class SocketGateway
  implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(SocketGateway.name);
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;

  constructor(private readonly socketService: SocketService) {}

  @SubscribeMessage('statusUpdate')
  updateStatus(data: any) {
    this.server.emit('statusUpdate', data);
  }

  handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    return this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: any): any {
    return this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to connect using postman by connecting to this URL
`ws://localhost:5010`

which results in this error `socket hang up`
not really sure why is it behaving this way and no sufficient information to debug it.
would really appreciate if someone could share a hint on where to look.

I am on macOS Monterey: 12.0.1 ( last update )

installed Websocket libs:

@nestjs/platform-socket.io: 8.2.4

@nestjs/websockets": 8.2.4

Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Through e2e testing, you can try with this example:

```
import * as WebSocket from 'ws'
beforeAll(async () => {
  const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
      SocketModule,
    ],
  }).compile()

  app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication()
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app))
  await app.init()
})

it('should connect successfully', (done) => {
  const address = app.getHttpServer().listen().address()
  const baseAddress = `http://[${address.address}]:${address.port}`

  const socket = new WebSocket(baseAddress)

  socket.on('open', () => {
    console.log('I am connected! YEAAAP')
    done()
  })

  socket.on('close', (code, reason) => {
    done({ code, reason })
  })

  socket.on ('error', (error) => {
    done(error)
  })
})
```

[this example is based on this answer](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/97#issuecomment-722790467)